# how i display seller products on seller dashboard no other seller can delete or edit his product and show seller product to buyer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Here is the application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
   
  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:role])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :first_name, :last_name,
     :user_name, :Address, :city, :postal_code, :password_confirmation, :role)}
  end

  protected

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
if current_user.Buyer?
   root_path
else
  dashboard_path
 end 
  end
end
```

here is the home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    
    def homepage
    end

    def dashboard
    
    end
    
end
```

Here is the product controller

```
class ProductsController < InheritedResources::Base

  private

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, images: [])
    end

end
```

Here is the product model

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true
    validate :image_type
    belongs_to :user
    private
     def image_type
        if images.attached? ==false
            errors.add(:images, " are missing")
        end
     end
    end
```

Here is the user model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 validates :email, format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i, message: "Email invalid"  },
   uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 254 }
   has_many :products
   
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  
   enum role: { Buyer: 0, Seller: 1 } 
   devise :registerable, :confirmable
end
```

Here is the schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_03_03_093335) do

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.integer "record_id", null: false
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "description"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "role", default: 0
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "user_name"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "Address"
    t.integer "postal_code"
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

In the home folder file dasboard.html.erb

```
 <h1>Dashboard</h1>

 <%= link_to 'Products', products_path %>
```

When user signup as a seller it should add products add product images delete product
and when someone signin as buyer the buyer see seller products only how i can implement this

Comment: you could try and look at something like the `cancancan` gem in order to restrict access: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: how i can do without gem

Comment: there are lots of ways you could do this without a gem, but using an existing gem like `cancancan` will make things a lot simpler, a lot quicker, and a lot more readable